# Create days array from Today till seven days ago with date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

In my React component, I have to render a list of days: from `Today - seven days ago`.

Like: `Today / Yesterday / Monday / Tuesday / Wednesday / Thursday / Friday`.

I am using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org).

```
  const generateDays = () => {
    const date: Date = new Date();
    const a = subDays(date, 4);
    const formatted = format(a, 'eeee', { locale: nl });

    return formatted;
  };
```

How do I accomplish this in an smooth way?

What I tried:

```
  const today = new Date();
  const sevenDaysAgo = subDays(today, 6);

  const sevenDays = eachDayOfInterval({ start: sevenDaysAgo, end: today });

  sevenDays.forEach((day) => {
    console.log(format(day, 'eeee', { locale: nl }));
  });
```

This returns:

```
['Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday', 'Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday']
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish. Yes, it is possible to filter the results of a query. But what is the query and what result does it give you? How do you want to filter it?

Comment: I can query and filter now with e.g `dayOffset: 3`. That will filter my results 3 days back, that's 'Saturday'. But tomorrow a `dayOffset: 3` will be 'Monday'. In the ui I have buttons like Monday, Tuesday and so on. Do you understand the problem?

Comment: Yes, I think so. You want the diff between the current date and e.g. next saturday. You should be able to use `getDay` for that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Answer (score 1):

To get the week day from the dayOffset (replace 'en-us' with your country's code if you're not American) you can do the following.

```
const offset_date = new Date();

offset_date.setDate(offset_date.getDate() + dayOffset);

const week_day = offset_date.toLocaleString('en-us', {weekday: 'long'});
```

Comment: sorry I adjusted my question a bit. I have to do it in steps. This is part one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [formatRelative](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.6/docs/formatRelative) function from the `date-fns` library, it formats the dates in words from a given date.

Here is a [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-tree-v6v3x7?file=/src/App.js) that might be helpful.